# Relation between memory host and memory arguments xms and xmx from Java

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-management

I have the following host with the memory details:

```
$free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7872       7579        292         17        483       3983
-/+ buffers/cache:       3112       4759 
Swap:         2047         14       2033
```

I have a java app running with the params  `-Xms200m -Xmx200m`, could someone please explain me why the VCZ is 3800076 and the RSS is 241304 (which is more of the Java params)

from the `ps -aux` command:

```
66345     6773  0.2  2.9 3800076 241304 ?      Sl   Apr1  12:06 /apps/myapps/myapp1/java/bin/java -Xms200m -Xmx200m
```

Comment: Which version of Java is that?

Comment: Using Java 8 in the host

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Memory used by Java process (as seen by the OS) is not only limited to Java Heap. There are a lot more memory areas that should be also counted:

- Metaspace (where class metadata resides);
- Code Cache (storage for JIT-compiled methods and all the generated code);
- Direct ByteBuffers;
- Memory-mapped files, including files mapped by JVM, e.g. all JAR files on the classpath;
- Thread stacks;
- JVM code itself and all the dynamic libraries loaded by Java Runtime;
- Other internal JVM structures.

Use [NativeMemoryTracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) JDK feature to get the detailed breakdown of memory areas used by JVM:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics
```

Comment: could you please add reference to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html. Then I'll upvote :-P

Comment: That makes it hard to plan VMs to deploy JVM applications. Used to be setting mx, mss, permgen to specific values below the physical memory size, and you're safe. Now I have a few JVM that have mx of 12g, and yet their VSS is twice that size and exceeds the total memory available on the box - which is a disaster waiting to happen, methinks.